# how can i show my custom (Day-Month-Year Hour:Min:Sec) time format on chartjs chart?

Tags: datetime, charts, chart.js, datetime-format

I want to show my custom (Day-Month-Year Hour:Min:Sec -->ex: 01-05-2019 14:06:47 PM) time format on chartjs chart

How Can i Show On chart xAxis Date Format Like This >> 
**Day-Month-Year Hour:Min:Sec -->ex: 01-05-2019 14:06:47 PM**

time format is `timeFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss a'` but on chart only shows Month,Day,Year

This is my code below and:
**Online Code On >>>** https://codepen.io/sibche2013/pen/XQWWbb

```
var timeFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss a';

    var config = {
        type:    'line',
        data:    {
            datasets: [

                {
                    label: "UK Dates",
                    data:  [{
                        x: "01-04-2014 02:15:50", y: 175
                    }, {
                        x: "12-04-2014 12:19:27", y: 177
                    }, {
                        x: "23-04-2014 22:25:47", y: 178
                    }, {
                        x: "28-04-2014 14:46:40", y: 182
                    }],
                    fill:  false,
                    borderColor: 'blue'
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title:      {
                display: true,
                text:    "Chart.js Time Scale"
            },
            scales:     {
                xAxes: [{
                    type:       "time",
                    time:       {
                        format: timeFormat,
                        tooltipFormat: 'll'
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'Date'
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'value'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        var ctx       = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
```